# How to release Inactive memory in Python3 back to OS?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a large `.npz` file (about 10GB), that contains 5 arrays. I have used a for loop to save the first 10 values of each array into a variable. After the loop ends python is utilizing more than 70% of total RAM.

Code:

```
x = np.load('file.npz')
for i in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'):
    locals()[i] = x[i][:10]

x.close()
del x
gc.collect()
```

I have tried deleting the reference to `.npz` file and used `gc.collect()` but it only releases a small amount of data. By using `psutil.virtual_memory()` this is the result:

```
svmem(total=16523776000, available=4784799744, percent=71.0, used=11129757696, free=4689756160, active=1481039872, inactive=9870499840, buffers=25161728, cached=679100416, shared=304119808, slab=238493696)
```

How do I release the inactive memory back to OS (Ubuntu 22.04)?